# How may delegate method from one protocol prevent execution of another one from another protocol?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection

Specifically, `connectionDidFinishDownloading:destinationURL:` from `<NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate>` prevented execution of `connection:DidReceiveData:` from `<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>`.
How could it be?

I was mistyped in naming method, and then just auto completed typo with Xcode, received `connectionDidFinishDownloading:destinationURL:` instead of `connectionDidFinishLoading`.
Then for a several days I could not realize why `connection:DidReceiveData:` wasn't called at all. So I've repaired everything, and now asking you: **why** is that?

Thx for responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a feature that is not well documented. NSURLConnection has two different delegate protocols: NSURLConnectionDataDelegate and NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate.

- NSURLConnectionDataDelegate: delegate methods used for loading data to memory.                   These delegate methods are all optional.
- NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate: delegate methods used to perform resource                    downloads directly to a disk file.  All the methods are optional with the exception of                     connectionDidFinishDownloading:destinationURL: which must be implemented in order to inform the                     delegate of the location of the finished download.

As you see, if you implemented connectionDidFinishDownloading:destinationURL: in your delegate. That will inform NSURLConnection you want to download the data to a disk file other than to memory as NSData. The target disk file is located in  the applications cache directory and is guaranteed to exist for the duration of the delegate callback. The implication is that the delegate should copy or move the download to a more persistent location.

So if you eliminate connectionDidFinishDownloading:destinationURL: from your delegate class implementation, connection:DidReceiveData: will get called instead.

How ever this is not the last story. When you implement connectionDidFinishDownloading:destinationURL: and then wanna access the downloaded file through destinationURL. Unfortunately the file isn't there. Gotcha, the delegate callback is for Newsstand apps. If you are not developing a newsstand app while you specify in the Info.plist, please keep away from NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate. Apple confirmed this is a bug from iOS 5 to iOS 7. Still not fixed yet:)